# Create new reference dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, dataframe

Whats the easiest way of going from this (data frame):

```
Project Folder Owner value1 values2
  A       B      C     100    200
  A       B      C     500    400
  D       E      F     100    200
  D       E      F     300    400
```

to this:

```
referenceID   value1 values2
  1             100    200
  1             500    400
  2             100    200
  2             300    400
```

and a second data frame with:

```
referenceID Project Folder Owner 
1             A       B      C
2             D       E      F
```

I though about using a label encoder but that will require me to concatenate "Project, Folder and Owner" into a new field  - which is ok as long as I keep the orignals, but seems like extra unnecessary work.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the second dataframe with a groupby on the original using Project, Folder, and Owner. Then create a list of the unique values of the index and feed those into a new dataframe. Assuming your original data is in a dataframe named df:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Project', 'Folder', 'Owner']).agg('sum')
df3 = pd.DataFrame([list(df2.index.unique().tolist()[x]) for x in range(len(df2.index.unique().tolist()))], columns=df2.index.name)
df3.insert(0, 'ReferenceId', df3.index + 1)
```

The result will look like this (your desired second dataframe):

```
    ReferenceId Project Folder  Owner
0   1           A       B       C
1   2           D       E       F
```

Answer (score 0):

This will generate the output you're looking for.

```
m = [['A', 'B', 'C', 100, 200],
     ['A', 'B', 'C', 500, 400],
     ['D', 'E', 'F', 100, 200],
     ['D', 'E', 'F', 300, 400]]

owner = {}
for row in m:
    key = tuple(row[:3])
    if key in owner:
        owner[key].append(row[3:])
    else:
        owner[key] = [row[3:]]

frame1 = []
frame2 = []
for i, key in enumerate(owner):
    frame2.append([i] + list(key))
    for row in owner[key]:
        frame1.append([i] + list(row))


print frame1
print frame2
```

Comment: I agree. But you're making an assumption that the user is familiar with pandas. My solution only depends on the standard library.

Comment: yeah I mentioned data frame on the question. I didn't down voted you btw

Answer (score -1):

In order to select your columns, if you know the number of the column, use the built-in call, otherway use `.ix` method:

```
%timeit df.loc[:,['value1','values2']]
out: 1000 loops, best of 3: 602 µs per loop

%timeit df[[3,4]]
out: 1000 loops, best of 3: 295 µs per loop

%timeit df.ix[:,['value1','values2']]
1000 loops, best of 3: 412 µs per loop
```

As for the groupby, well just use groupby:

```
df.groupby(['Project','Folder','Owner'],as_index = False).sum().drop(['value1','values2'],1)
```

Comment: where is the referenceID? and how do you update the original data frame with it?